# Javascript Variables - A variable variable is required

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, variable-assignment

The following code requires that the name of 2 variables are combined.

```
var myScroll; 
var orderit;
var id;   
$('.scrollable').each(function(){
    orderit += 1;
    $(this).attr('id', 'scrollp' + orderit);
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    myscroll = new iScroll( id );
});
```

So the problem is that the variable my scroll must be unique each time, so its name needs to be myscroll+orderit but I cannot name a variable like that.

Any ideas how to do this.

Marvellous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to dynamically generate variables is the wrong approach. It can be done *(though not in "strict mode")*, but it isn't advised.

Instead, you should be creating a collection. You could either use an Array or an Object.

---

With an Array, you can  use `.map()` to build a collection. Then use `.toArray()` to generate an Array.

```
var orderit = 0;
var myScroll = $('.scrollable').map(function(){
    this.id = 'scrollp' + (++orderit);
    return new iScroll( this.id );
}).toArray();
```

...and access them like:

```
myScroll[0];
myScroll[1];
  // ...and so on
```

---

If you instead want the `myScroll1, myScroll2` names, then use an Object.

```
var orderit = 0;
var scrolls = {};
$('.scrollable').each(function(){
    this.id = 'scrollp' + (++orderit);
    scrolls[ 'myScroll' + orderit ] = new iScroll( this.id );
});
```

...and access them like:

```
scrolls.myScroll1;
scrolls.myScroll2;
  // ...and so on
```

---

FYI: There's no need for `.attr()` to get and set the ID of an element. Just access it directly with `this.id` as I did in my answer.

---

**EDIT:** *I used the wrong value to build the object properties. Fixed.*

Answer (score 4):

Make `myScroll` an array, and `push()` onto it:

```
var myScroll = [];

var orderit;
var id;   
$('.scrollable').each(function(){
   orderit += 1;
   $(this).attr('id', 'scrollp' + orderit);
   id = $(this).attr('id');

   // push another iScroll() onto myScroll
   myScroll.push(new iScroll( id ));
 });
```

Note: In your code, you declared `myScroll` but later use `myscroll`. Check the case difference - I fixed it in my example.

Comment: I noticed that in your code before realising it was my mistake. Implementing it now

Comment: Each incarnation of myScroll must be a separate variable. Does this script do that. That is it should say myScroll1, myScroll2, myScroll3 etc...

Comment: @RobinKnight Internally they are distinct variables, just aggregated together as an array.  Access them as `myScroll[0], myScroll[1],...myScroll[n]`